# Cannot create ESXi storage on second NVMe

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I'm really searching all over for a solution for hours. I do not have physical access to the datacenter, I have KVM and SSH access. Server is a Supermicro X11 model.

The server has 2 NVMe disks. I have installed ESXi 6.7u3 on one of them (both were visible during setup). Now in ESX Web client there is a single storage as expected, and I can see both drives;

[Datastore view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAEmC.png)

[Devices view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R78Sn.png)

If I click "New Datastore", during the wizard it says there is not any available device to create a datastore. When I click the first drive details, as you can see "New Datastore" is grayed out and looking at the partitioning, this is the drive I chose during installation and I can assume that this drive is attached to the default datastore1.

[Device 1 details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XcN7.png)

If I click the second drive, you can see that the "New Datastore" button is active, so I assume this is the other drive that ESXi is not installed on, so I should be able to create a datastore on it. But if you look at the partitioning, it's exactly same as the first drive. Although it says "there are no available devices" if I click the "New Datastore" button from the main Storage screen (remember above), I can click the button in the below screenshot and continue to the end. I did not create the datastore on this drive because I'm afraid something will break.

[Device 2 details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hixZS.png)

So why are these 2 drives have exact same partitioning on them if I installed ESXi on only first drive and why is the difference between two "New Datastore" buttons, one is working other does not allow me? Is there some raid setup here that I cannot see? I have rebooted the server, checked BIOS, looked for some "press this combination to enter raid setup" message during boot but there are no indications that the disks are in a RAID array. How can I determine this?

Any help or directions appreciated. Thanks if you read this far.

Comment: It looks like it is indeed possible to create RAID volumes with NVME drives on a Supermicro X11 board. This document describes how to do the necessary BIOS setup (see section 5, page 15ff): https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/AOC-VROCxxxMOD_Windows.pdf BTW I found this doc with a simple Google query for "Supermicro X11 nvme raid"

Comment: I have 2 Samsung NVMe on a Dell server with ESXi installed on one of them, no issues so far. As you have mentioned, since drives are not in RAID array, you can try reinstalling ESXi. I would actually recommend you installing it on a separate small SSD if possible.

Comment: The two drives are in fact mirrored because the UUIDs shown in the two Device details screenshots are identical.